# How to handle Cross site scripting issue in PHP with msSQL server?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, cross-site

I have a reported issue like Cross site scripting issue. When I enter window.location.href='http://google.com' it saves into database. But while listing it in a page it redirects into http://google.com. I fixed the issue with fliter_sanitize_string. However, it is required to handle each variable one by one, Is there any common way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using codeigniter, you can config that in application/config/config.php

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

to anticipate xss.

Comment: you can try it out using same method that codeigniter used, to sanitize the string.